# How to make an Alfred workflow with twice searches?

Tags: workflow, alfred

I want to make an Alfred Workflow, and I have made one before, it only needs one input, but now it may need two.

The situation is as below. With the keyword, firstly I will get the results through the first API, then I should use the result(select one) as the keyword to go through the second api and find the results.

If only one input, I know I should use `Script Filter`, but after the first search and list the results, I should use it as the second input, how can I realize that?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just connect two `Script Filter` objects and whatever you set as the `arg` of the actioned result will pass as the input of the second `Script Filter`.